# Appdynamics problems to install in jboss app server

Tags: windows, jboss, wildfly, appdynamics

I followed the instructions on the website of appdynamic, but when I was following this step:

[image: screenshot image of steps]

When I ran standalone.bat this error appears:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wildfly/common/net/HostName
    at org.jboss.logmanager.ExtLogRecord.<init>(ExtLogRecord.java:87)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.Logger.log(Logger.java:796)
    at org.jboss.logging.JBossLogManagerLogger.doLogf(JBossLogManagerLogger.java:53)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.logf(Logger.java:2398)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceLogger_$logger.greeting(ServiceLogger_$logger.java:40)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.<clinit>(ServiceContainerImpl.java:91)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainer$Factory.create(ServiceContainer.java:250)
    at org.jboss.as.server.BootstrapImpl$ShutdownHook.register(BootstrapImpl.java:231)
    at org.jboss.as.server.BootstrapImpl$ShutdownHook.access$100(BootstrapImpl.java:221)
    at org.jboss.as.server.BootstrapImpl.<init>(BootstrapImpl.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.server.Bootstrap$Factory.newInstance(Bootstrap.java:278)
    at org.jboss.as.server.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:352)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:320)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:593)
```

Comment: Have you made any changes in standalone.bat file?

Comment: no, i only changed the standalone.conf.bat

Comment: Can you share what you changed in standalone.conf.bat in txt format not pic

Answer (score 1):

1. To install the Java Agent on JBoss EAP or JBoss Wildfly, you need to initialize the JVM. Run the following parameter:

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman,com.singularity,org"
If you do not initialize the JVM, the installation throws a "class not found" exception.

2. Add the following to the end of the standalone.conf file in the JAVA_OPTS section.

-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -Xbootclasspath/p:
/jboss-logmanager-.jar

JDK9 and above, -Xbootclasspath/p option has been removed; use -Xbootclasspath/a instead.

-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -Xbootclasspath/a:
/jboss-logmanager-.jar

3. You can find the all installation process on the latest installation document:

https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO45/JBoss+and+Wildfly+Startup+Settings#JBossandWildflyStartupSettings-InitializetheJVM